# Inserting associated models in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to insert an invoice struct along with its associated invoice items.  I'm able to insert the invoice data, and call an anonymous function to validate, cast, and insert each item.  Since insert/2 does not produce a return, how can I get the invoice_id for the items while still being able to roll back the entire transaction if one item fails validation or insertion?

I've put the code in my own repo, here it is:

```
def insertassoc(params) do
 Repo.transaction(fn ->    
  i = Invoice.changeset(params["data"], :create)
    if i.valid? do
      Repo.insert(i)
    else
      Repo.rollback(i.errors)
    end

  insert_include = fn k ->
    c = InvoiceItem.changeset(k, :create)
    if c.valid? do
      Repo.insert(c)
    else
      Repo.rollback(c.errors)
    end
  end

  for include <- params["includes"] do
    insert_include.(Map.merge(include, %{"invoice_id" => ????}))
  end

 end)
end
```

and here is how I use it from my controller:

```
def create(conn, params) do
 case InvoiceRepo.insertassoc(params) do
  {:ok, x} ->
    json conn, Map.merge(params, %{"message" => "OK"})
  {:error, x} ->
    json conn |> put_status(400), Map.merge(params, %{"message" 
    => "Error"})
 end
end
```

There aren't many up to date examples out there with Ecto, so sorry if these are noob questions ;-).  Anyone have an idea? I tried putting the invoice insert in a private function, and using a case block to determine whether the main transaction should roll back, but I couldn't figure out how to get the invoice id back from that either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Repo.insert/1` actually returns the model you have just inserted. You also want to decouple the validation from the transaction handling as much as possible. I would suggest something as follows:

```
invoice = Invoice.changeset(params["data"], :create)
items   = Enum.map(params["includes"], &InvoiceItem.changeset(&1, :create))

if invoice.valid? && Enum.all?(items, & &1.valid?) do
  Repo.transaction fn ->
    invoice = Repo.insert(invoice)
    Enum.map(items, fn item ->
      item = Ecto.Changeset.change(item, invoice_id: invoice.id)
      Repo.insert(item)
    end)
  end
else
  # handle errors
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much more elegant. BTW, for those who will use this, here's how I handled the errors for them to be encoded into JSON: `errors = Enum.map(items, & (&1.errors))
      |> Enum.into([invoice.errors])
      |> Enum.map(& (Enum.into(&1, %{}))){:errors, errors}`

Comment: The API has changed now so that `Repo.insert` should be replaced with `Repo.insert!` to return the model or raise an error inside the transaction.

Comment: On top of that, Ecto now also supports `put_assoc` which allows you to change the parent schema alongside its children, and that would make the code above much cleaner!

Comment: @JoséValim - Could you please help elaborate how put_assoc will make the code simpler? I am trying to insert a model and its association at the same time. Model A has many Model Bs. I was thinking creating changesets for Model A and a changeset for model B and providing modelA's change set in put_assoc will do it. Nope. Didn't work. For example -  csModelA =  %ModelA{} |> change |> ModelA.create_changeset(params) and csModelB = %ModelB{} |> change |> put_assoc(:modelA, csModelA) |>  ModelB.create_changeset. This barfs when adding model B complaining that the foreign key is not there

Answer (score 10):

In Ecto 2.0 you would be doing something like:

```
%My.Invoice{}
|> Ecto.Changeset.change
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:invoice_items, [My.InvoiceItem.changeset(%My.InvoiceItem{}, %{description: "bleh"})])
|> My.Repo.insert!
```

(The accepted answer works pre 2.0, also, Valim mentions in the comments of that answer of the existence of `put_assoc`)